# CoreText - Spaces not wrapping?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-text

I noticed in `CoreText`, in developing my own custom `UITextView` and also looking at Apple's `SimpleTextInput`, that a space or " " doesn't break (or move onto the next line) when it runs out of space at the end of the line its on. Instead, it continues to be drawn on the same line past the width bounds of the view.

Is this a bug, or is this the intended behavior? Is there anyway to get spaces to wrap / break onto the next line with `CoreText`?

UPDATE: Tried individually setting spaces to have `kCTLineBreakByCharWrapping` attribute and it didn't work. Thinking maybe there is some unicode character I could enter instead of `@" "` that might get it to work properly? Trying to avoid having to manually put this in the code for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `-` instead of " ", than before I draw the text I should make the place where the `-` 
is been cleaned as blank. So you can do something you like in blank space, I draw some `emoji` in these places, It works for me. You can try `~ ^.^`

Answer (score 7):

It is by design that whitespace alone does not trigger a line break.  Only a visible character that would cross the margin triggers a line break.

You can find the width of whitespace at the end of a `CTLine` using `CTLineGetTrailingWhitespaceWidth`.

You can probably make a whitespace character cause a line break (if it crosses the margin) by attaching a `CTRunDelegate` attribute to it.  You will have to make the `CTRunDelegate` report the appropriate width, ascent, and descent, which you'll probably have to look up in the `CTFont`.  You can probably use a single instance of `CTRunDelegate` for all of the spaces that are set in the same font and size.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I mimiced the behavior of a UITextView. In that, if you do a space at the very end of a line, the space is appended, but the cursor just stays in its place.

Comment: It appears CTRunDelegate actually *does not* help if it is attached to a whitespace. This also goes for normal nobr spaces.